# Installation of git in CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation, git

I am writing a software. For my work I need to connect to the common `git` repository, when I turned out that the necessary packages are not installed on my computer. Is it enough to install a single `git` package into the system?

```
$ sudo yum -y install git
```

Or does it require something more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CentOS,

```
sudo yum -y install git
```

is indeed enough to install `git`.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, this is enough for `git` to work. Additionally, you may want to install the *“Development tools”* group of packages, which includes `git`, but most probably not the latest version:

```
$ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development tools"
```

To see what is included in this group:

```
$ yum group info "Development tools"
```

```
┌────────────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Mandatory Packages │ Default packages │ Optional Packages │
╞════════════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ autoconf           │ asciidoc         │ cmake             │
│ automake           │ byacc            │ expect            │
│ binutils           │ ctags            │ rpmdevtools       │
│ bison              │ diffstat         │ rpmlint           │
│ flex               │ git              │                   │
│ gcc                │ intltool         │                   │
│ gcc-c++            │ jna              │                   │
│ gdb                │ ltrace           │                   │
│ glibc-devel        │ patchutils       │                   │
│ libtool            │ perl-Fedora-VSP  │                   │
│ make               │ perl-generators  │                   │
│ pkgconf            │ pesign           │                   │
│ pkgconf-m4         │ source-highlight │                   │
│ pkgconf-pkg-config │ systemtap        │                   │
│ redhat-rpm-config  │ valgrind         │                   │
│ rpm-build          │ valgrind-devel   │                   │
│ rpm-sign           │                  │                   │
│ strace             │                  │                   │
└────────────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

---

***If you want to install the latest version***: on CentOS 7 and 8:

1. Install the *“Development tools”* group of packages

   ```
   $ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development tools"
   ```

   Full set including *«Optional Packages»*

   ```
   $ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development tools" --with-optional
   ```
2. Remove the default `git` package

   ```
   $ sudo yum remove git
   ```
3. Install additional packages, which are needed for the build process

   ```
   $ sudo yum -y install zlib-devel xmlto
   ```
4. Download and unzip the actual version: https://github.com/git/git
5. Git installation (see the `INSTALL` file)

   ```bash
   $ make configure # as yourself
   $ ./configure    # as yourself
   $ make all doc   # as yourself
   $ make install install-doc install-html # as root
   ```

   This will install the `git` programs in the `/usr/local/bin` folder. If necessary, add this folder to the `$PATH` variable.
6. Checking installation

   ```bash
   $ git --version # 2.27.0
   ```

---

Official site: https://git-scm.com/

Comment: Would you explain why we need "zlib-devel" and "xmlto"?